# What is the smartest way to define values in function?

Tags: php, function, if-statement

Is there any smarter / better / faster / easier way to define values in `PHP` functions?

I am using:

```
function get_user($id){
if($id == "1"){
return "Ram";
}
elseif($id == "2"){
return "Shyam";
}
elseif($id == "5"){
return "Ramu";
}
elseif($id == "7"){
return "Raman";
}
elseif($id == "8"){
return "Laxman";
}
elseif($id == "9"){
return "Bharat";
}
}
```

Comment: What do you need to do if `$id` is passed in as `11`?

Comment: I don't see anything being defined in what you posted. You are simply returning a string based on a number passed to the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an associative array in the function.

```
function get_user($id){
    $arr =["1" => "Ram", 
           "2" => "Shyam",
           "5" => "Ramu",
           "7" => "Raman",
           "8" => "Laxman",
           "9" => "Bharat"];

    return $arr[$id];
    // Or:
    // if(isset($arr[$id])) return $arr[$id];
}
```